# item.Update() on an empty library - takes forever

Tags: 2010, updatelistitems

I'm using

`SPListItem someItem = web.Lists[listName].AddItem(string.Empty, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, listRelativeFolderUrl)`

to add a folder to an empty library. When I call

`someItem.Update()`

The debugger just sits and processes that line, but never finishes. This is an empty library, there is absolutely nothing in it. What could be wrong here?

Comment: It seems that item.Update() does not work when the debugger is active (i.e. a breakpoint is set on that location (or one before it) and I step over it). If I put a breakpoint on the line after, it seems to work and the item is created. This isn't really the 'answer' but can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: if you set a breakpoint, it's going to stop on that line regardless of what code's on it. remove the breakpoint.

Comment: @jpollar I'm well aware of that. The problem was, when the breakpoint was on item.Update(), I pressed Play and the debugger could not process the item.Update() call. I've seen this before. Sometimes certain function don't work well with a debugger attached, especially for COM objects.

Comment: I've never witnessed that. Yes, it hangs until you take the next step. It's supposed to do that. Did you get an error? Or a timeout at least?